# Should I install MPFR after installing GMP?

Tags: c++, gmp, mpfr

Hello I have a simple question: If I have installed GMP-6.2.0 then I don't need to install MPFR and MPIR in linux?

Comment: The [GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html#Floating_002dpoint-Functions) still recommends MPFR for floating point numbers depending on your precision and rounding requirements. I guess it depends what you're using these for?

Comment: @Rup: Ok. Thank you. I need float point high precision.